# Delete dropdown values only 275 to 500 when I've values from 10 to 500

Tags: jquery

```
var getdenomvalue = 275;
var a = 0;
var removeDollarSign;
var numberValue;
var selectdenom = document.getElementById("t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_Denomination1_ddl");
for (var j = 0; j < selectdenom.length; j++) {
    var getText = selectdenom[j].text;
    if (getText) {
        removeDollarSign = getText.replace('$', '');
        numberValue = Number(removeDollarSign);
        if (numberValue == getdenomvalue ) {                                
            selectdenom.remove(j);
            a++;
            getdenomvalue = getdenomvalue + a * 25;
        }
    }
}
```

My dropdown has values from 10 to 500. I want to delete from 275 to 500. When I use above it's just deleting one value 275, other values are skipped. What's wrong in the above code?

Comment: numberValue == getdenomvalue  needs to be: numberValue >= getdenomvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a much faster approach using jquery.

```
<script>
var getdenomvalue = 275;
    $().ready(function(){
    $('#t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_Denomination1_ddl option').each(function()
        {
              $(this).val().replace("$","") >= getdenomvalue ? $(this).remove() : null;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/nhoo6rhc/2/

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe you can check this

```
$("option[value='foo']").remove();
```

or better (if you have few selects in the page):

```
$("#select_id option[value='foo']").remove();
```

for more information check this

[remove event jquery](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get existing dropdown values and add to array
var optionArray = $('.selector').children().toArray();

// Remove any values above 275
optionArray.splice(275);

// Empty the select box
$('.selector').empty();

// Loop through the array and append tho the select box
$.each(optionArray, function(key, value) {
    $('.selector').append(value);
})
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/zz5k34ke/3/